# Python: Regex for multiple characters in a line?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to understand and know how i can combine all these regex into one line.
I want to ignore lines that have the following characters (?,+,-,insA,insC,insG,insT,insU, and any line tht has ins and some number immediately after it, for example ins34 or ins99)
The following seems to work but not pretty. Any help is really appreciated.

```
    f1=re.search(r'\?(.+)$',line)
    f2=re.search(r'\+(.+)$',line)
    f3=re.search(r'\-(.+)$',line)
    f4=re.search(r'\insA(.+)$',line)
    f5=re.search(r'\insC(.+)$',line)
    f6=re.search(r'\insG(.+)$',line)
    f7=re.search(r'\insT(.+)$',line)
    f8=re.search(r'\insU(.+)$',line)
```

Comment: Why do you have those `(.+)$` bits?

Comment: Sounds like you want to read up on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: And why did you backslash the `i`s? (Or the `-`, but it's a bit more plausible that you'd think that was a metacharacter. By the way, `-` isn't a metacharacter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if not re.search("[-?+]|ins[ACGTU\d]", line):
    # Do something
```

It will only run the "Do something" part if `line`doesn't have a `?`, a `+`, a `-`, a `insA`, a `insC`, a `insG`, a `insT`, a `insU`, or a `ins` followed by a number in it.